# How count objects with element value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, count

I need your help.
I have for example such array:

```
  var array = [{
    "name": "Tony",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "name": "Helen",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "year": "2005"
}, {
    "name": "Tony",
    "year": "2008"
}, {
    "name": "Max",
    "year": "2005"
}];
```

How i can count them by year and get something like this:

```
2010 = 2 times;
2005 = 2 times;
2008 = 1 time;
```

Thank you

Comment: **1.** Create an object to store counter of each unique year **2.** Loop over array **3.** Check if key exists in counter obj, if yes increment else add as 0.

Comment: And there's no need to follow steps, you've got an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khvz49xr/)

```
var countObj = {};
for( var counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++ )
{
   var yearValue = array [ counter ].year;
   if ( !countObj[ yearValue ] )
   {
      countObj[ yearValue ] = 0;
   }
   countObj[ yearValue ] ++;
}
console.log( countObj );
```

Comment: You could try a recursive function for improved code?

Comment: @EnriqueQuero can you try and post your own answer? If you find any other issue with the code, please mention.

Comment: I don't know but there are some trolls in StackOverFLow. I had two Upvotes and some trolls have downvote my answer...

Comment: @sapikelio I have been downvoted 2-3 times already myself. At least someone should leave a comment if there is anything wrong

Comment: Hahahah Maybe the comment they leave you could be "Your answer is correct, but my answer need to be the correct answer. for this reason I downvote your answer, in order to my answer looks the right answer. Xo xo",

Comment: @Sapikelio, I'm pretty sure that's what it is. There was no need for the drive-by downvote (my answer was downvoted but then that was rescinded once an answer had been chosen as correct).

Comment: @Andy & @ Sapikelio well said. Anything that can be done about it. Happens too often for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var array = [{
    "name": "Tony",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "name": "Helen",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "year": "2005"
}, {
    "name": "Tony",
    "year": "2008"
}, {
    "name": "Max",
    "year": "2005"
}];
var map={}
for (var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
   if ( !map[ array [ i ].year ] ){
      map[ array [ i ].year ] = 0;
   }
   map[ array [ i ].year] ++;
}
console.log( map );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dr335y5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Here `arrange` uses `reduce` to build an object using the years as keys. It accepts a `prop` argument so that you can build the object as you see fit.

```
function arrange(arr, prop) {
  return arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
    var key = c[prop];
    p[key] = p[key] || 0;
    p[key]++;
    return p;
  }, {});
}
```

You can then iterate over the key/values of that object and print out the results for `year`:

```
var obj = arrange(array, 'year');
for (var p in obj) {
  console.log(p + ' = ' + obj[p] + ' times');
}
```

Or even by `name`:

```
var obj = arrange(array, 'name');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/zdubus9s/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to re-invent the wheel.
This and many more methods are exposed by a third-party JS library, called "lodash"; old name was "underscore". All its methods or most of them are exposed like

```
_.methodName(listName, iteratorFunction)
```

You can download it at: https://lodash.com/

Once you download and include lodash your script in your html, go to your function and do:

```
_.groupBy(yourArrayVariable, function(item){
    return item.year;
});
```

**WARNING**
This method will not return an array. It will return a JSON, in which the keys are represented by the "item.year" through the whole original array, and the values will be an array for each year listed. Every such array is a list of objects having the same "year" value:

```
{
   "2010" : [
        { "name" : "Tony", "year" : "2010" },
        { "name" : "Helen", "year" : "2010" }
   ],
   "2011" : [ ..... ]
}
```

Lodash has **lots** of useful methods anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [{
    "name": "Tony",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "name": "Helen",
    "year": "2010"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "year": "2005"
}, {
    "name": "Tony",
    "year": "2008"
}, {
    "name": "Max",
    "year": "2005"
}];

var result = {};
array.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log(data.year);
    result[data.year] = result[data.year] ? ++result[data.year] : 1;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```